# How to get active/showed responsive columns in DataTables

Tags: datatables

I am trying to get some indicator of how many active columns is in a responsive display so I need what are active and how many of them.

I did not find anything.

Thnx

Comment: When you say active, do you mean you're trying to determine a list of currently visible columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. On DataTables forum they showed a way!
Link->
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/60092/datatables-responsive-mode-get-active-columns